# Graphics with bottom border for signature capture

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, rules, svg

I am generating PDF documents using pdflatex with signature images which are pre-converted with Inkscape to pdf.

The current template looks like this ({{ tags }} are django template tags):

```
\noindent \begin{tabular}{l l l}
CUSTOMER: &   \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{{ customer_sig2 }} & Date: {% now "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" %}\\
                         & {{ qb_full_name|upper }}      & \\
REP:          & \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{{ rep_sig2 }}  & Date:  {% now "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" %}\\
                         & {{ qb_rep_name|upper }}
\end{tabular}
```

Below is rough example of what I currently have and what I need (link):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1G30.gif

The signature images are created as PDF with Inkscape from svg base64 data. It seems Inkscape automatically crops to nearest edges. Thats called from python without many options - `x = Popen(['/usr/bin/inkscape', tmpfile.name, '--export-pdf=%s' % pdf.name])`

How can I best recreate the example image in latex?

EDIT:

Current signatures after help from Przemyslaw, using the following code (showing bottom and left and right margins of page):

```
\noindent \begin{tabular}{lc}
CUSTOMER: & \includegraphics[height=1.35cm,width=6.1cm,keepaspectratio]{{ customer_sig2 }}\\
\cline{2-2}
 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\rule{0mm}{4mm} Date: {% now "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" %} }
 \end{tabular}
 \hfill \begin{tabular}{lr}
 REP: & \includegraphics[height=1.35cm,width=6.5cm,keepaspectratio]{{ rep_sig2 }}\\
\cline{2-2}
& \multicolumn{1}{r}{\rule{0mm}{4mm} Date: {% now "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" %} }
\end{tabular}
```

[image: SignaturesAfterEdit]

FYI - I'm using jSignature plugin to capture the signature.. THe standard box dimension is 378x95px
Example of signature being pushed down by height of image (this would have been a fixed width with keep aspect ratio, no fixed height specified, see hrule for rep signature is nudged down a bit):

[image: SignaturePushedDown]

Comment: Note that you can convert the SVG to TikZ/PGF with InkScape, which might be easier to handle than the PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution, with pictures changed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabular}{l l l}
CUSTOMER: &   \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{at} & Date: \\%{% now "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" %}\\
                         & {\url{ qb_full_name|upper }}      & \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
REP:          & \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{at}  & Date:  \\%{% now "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" %}\\
                         & {\url{ qb_rep_name|upper }}
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
Second version:
\bigskip

\noindent \begin{tabular}{lc}
CUSTOMER: &   \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=1.5cm]{at}\\
\cline{2-2}
 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{ Date: 05/23/2013}
\end{tabular}
\hspace{1mm}
\begin{tabular}{l c}
REP:          & \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=1.5cm]{at}\\
\cline{2-2}
  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\rule{0mm}{4mm} Date: 05/23/2013}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Two tables in one line. Package `url` for underline char. Frame around at.png is a picture. I have removed `keepaspectratio` to show the begaviour of `Date: 05/23/2013`, one of them with correction of depth.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I was looking for; I want to insert a _bottom border_ for each _image_. I can't tell if your image had a border around it already, and the url part in your tex script is wrapping the names... which I would think would place lines under the text, not the signature.

Comment: @vonseel What about a second version?

Comment: Much better. I kept keep aspect ratio and removed the width argument, because varying widths seemed to push one of the tables down a bit since the image aspect ratios vary. I don't want to skew the aspect ratio though. Is there anyway to set the fixed width and preserve aspect ratio, (signatures will have varying height), and not push the table down? Maybe having a 2 column page-width table where the contents of each are aligned to the bottom (pushing both dates to the bottom of a row)?

Comment: @vonseel Putting here (dummy) signatures could help us. They are probably enclosed in some maximal rectangular, which should be preserved.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of that. I added more information in the original post. The box dimensions are 378px wide, 95px tall, by default -- BUT -- I'm not sure if it comes out of Inkscape with the same aspect ratio, or it trims to the edge of the lines

Comment: @vonseel So for safety you may add `\rule{0mm}{max height of sinature box}` before a picture with a signature, if lack of it is the cause pushing (an element of?) table down. Have you got an example of such behaviour?

Comment: Przemyslaw - thanks so much for the help. I added another picture with what you asked for. Do the order of width and height in the includegraphics options change the priority of either? I would like these images to be approx half width of the page, but can't set that without fixing the height if it's going to make the hrules uneven.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8927/discussion-between-vonseel-and-przemyslaw-scherwentke)